# How to block minus value using v-on:click at Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue component like below. 
But I want to stop when the counter is 0, even though it is clicked. 
How can I use that method in this case?
The only method is I have to make some method to block it? 
Thank you so much for reading.

```
<button v-on:click="counter.document -= 1">-</button>
    <h3>{{counter.document}}</h3>
<button v-on:click="counter.document += 1">+</button>

data() {
    return {
        counter: {
            document:0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dont jump on frameworks before you learn js please. just an advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to stop when the counter is 0, even though it is clicked.

Just adding a conditional checking before proceeding. Adding this line:
`if (this.count === 0) return`. Below is a working demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    count: 0
  },
  methods: {
    increment () {
      this.count += 1
    },
    decrement () {
      if (this.count === 0) return
      this.count -= 1
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>{{ count }}</h2>
  <button @click="increment">+</button>
  <button @click="decrement">-</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this. You can use the `disabled` attribute in your negative button when the value is becoming less than or equal to **0**. See the following code.

```
<button
  v-on:click="counter.document -= 1"
  :disabled="counter.document <= 0"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you have a lot of ways to achieving that one of them is this

`<button v-on:click=" if(counter.document>0){counter.document -= 1}">-</button>`

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid complex operation in `Template` Instead use `methods` property

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data(){
   return {
     value: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
   subtract() {
     if(this.value) {
       this.value -= 1
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <p> {{ value  }}</p>
  <button @click="value+=1">Add 1</button>
  <button @click="subtract" :disabled="!value ? 'true': undefined">Subtract 1</button>
</div>
```